# Is it true that the Jewish people signed O instead of X at Ellis Island?

Tags: 20th-century

I was trying to understand the etymology and history for the word 'kike'. With discovering some stuff on the Internet.

After searching on many sources, I found out that Jewish people on Ellis Island signed 'O' instead of 'X' because of relevance towards Christianity. Apparently, the religious slur originated from 'kikel' which means circle.

According to Oxford University Press's blog. https://blog.oup.com/2009/10/ethnic-slurs-kike/

> The second hypothesis turns round the Yiddish word for “circle” and has two variants. According to the main of them, on Ellis Island those immigrating Jews who knew neither English nor the Roman script were asked to put an X near their names, but looked upon it as a picture of the cross, a symbol of their former persecution, and instead put a circle. One of the variants of the Yiddish word for “circle” can be transcribed as kaykl, and this is said to be the etymon of Kike. Could the English speaking officials on Ellis Island isolate one Yiddish word in the speech of the Jewish people they dealt with, use it mockingly, and make it famous? I am afraid that we have here an example of the rich Ellis Island folklore that produced a Jew Shaun Ferguson and a Chinese man Sam Ting.

Another thing was this

> According to the Oxford English Dictionary, it may be an alteration of the endings –ki or –ky common in the personal names of Jews in eastern Europe who immigrated to the United States in the early 20th century.[2]

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kike

So, what is true? Did the Jewish people really sign O instead of X? Is there more information about the whole of the subject?

Comment: This smells of fish.  Plenty of Jewish people were literate in those days, so the "mark with an X" for the unlettered would not apply.  (My grandmother immigrated about a century ago, and was one of the few people in her village who could read and write.  She didn't sign with an X either (albeit, not Jewish)).

Comment: If that was the case, you wouldn't expect the people making the name to use the Yiddish word- the context doesn't make sense for it to have been uttered.

Comment: Of some interest, although only tangential relevance, in Israel the plus sign is often reduced to three points.

Comment: The quoted section seems to be saying *"this theory has been put forward, but it probably isn't true"* - "I am afraid that we have here an example of the **rich Ellis Island folklore**..." - ie, this is an urban legend. (It is a bit unclear at first, but that's definitely the sense I get from reading it)

Comment: Is there any evidence that illiterate Jews "signed" with a circle? Did they do that in Poland, Germany, or Lebanon? If not, why would they do that in the US? Why would they interpret X as a Christian symbol, and not as an aleph?

Comment: @LuísHenrique i am afraid you had less organized immigration procedure when you moved to Poland or Germany, so not many things had to be signed